# mysqld fails on F16

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql and phpmyadmin via, yum. I get the message

```
#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

The problem though, is with mysql itself.

```
# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start mysqld.service
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
```

`/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` is empty, but I'm unsure where to look next?

Any ideas?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep syslog`? `grep log-error /path/to/my.cnf`?

Comment: @quanta the log file is `/var/log/mysql.log` from `my.cnf` but that file doesn't exist?

Comment: `touch /var/log/mysql.log && chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql.log`, restart MySQL to see what does it say.

Comment: @quanta still empty, sometimes the `service mysqld start` command hangs

Comment: The log file you should look at is `/var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with help from [this site](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), seemed to do the trick.

```
## Remi Dependency on Fedora 17, 16
rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm 
rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm

## Fedora 17 ##
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/remi-release-17.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember once I fixed this problem with folowing solution:

try:

```
yum -enablerepo=remi install mysql-libs mysql.x86_64 mysql-devel.x86_64 mysql-server php-mysql
```

then:

```
Mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `Error getting repository data for remi, repository not found`